# Installation of Passenger version 6.0.0 for Rails 4.2.0/ruby 2.3.3/ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nginx, passenger

I am installing a ubuntu 18.04 server for my Rails 4.2.0/ruby 2.3.3 app with the command `passenger-install-nginx-module`. The installation went stuck twice without error. The passenger version is 6.0.0 which is the latest. Do I need to downplay the the `passenger` version for the combination of Rails 4.2.0/ruby 2.3.3?

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache and not Nginx, but I have succeeded deploying a Rails 2.3.18 app on ruby 1.8.7 while running Passenger 6.0 on ruby 2.5.3

I am setting custom ruby with `PassengerRuby` and setting gem path using environment variables `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME`

I recommend you enable this option to help you troubleshoot your issue

`PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on`

Hope this helps